# Cannot comform type when implementing max iterator with own typeclass in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement max iterator(like in Ruby) by using my own typeclass Max and List instance. But I cannot make the type correct. Does that mean 'b' cannot be same as 'a'? But what is I would like to get max item by their own value?

```hs
class Max t where
  c_max :: (a->b) -> t a -> a

instance Max [] where
  c_max f [a] = a
  c_max f (x:xs) = max (f x) (c_max f xs)

main = putStrLn $ show $ c_max (\x-> x) [1,2]
```

Comment: You will need an `Ord` type constraint, in order to compare two items.

Comment: Furthermore your function will here return a `b`, not an `a`.

Comment: Yeah I think  b is fine. I need to think a good recursive way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot make the type correct. Does that mean `b` cannot be same as `a`?

It *can*, but the two are not per se the same.

The problem however does not arise from the use of `c_max` in the `main` function. There are basically two problems here.

First, you perform a mapping from `a` to `b`, but you did not restrict `b` to a type that is an instance of `Ord`. As a result, we can not compare the two `b`s to decide what `b` is the largest. We thus should add an `Ord b` typeconstraint:

```
class Max t where
    c_max :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> t a -> a
```

In your `instance Max []` your `max` compares two `b`s, and *returns* the largest `b`. But given your type signature, you want to return the corresponding `a`. We can implement this with:

```
instance Max [] where
    c_max f [a] = a
    c_max f (x:xs) | f x > f mx = x
                   | otherwise = mx
        where mx = c_max f xs
```

For example:

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ show $ c_max (\x-> x) [1,2]
2
```

The above is not the most efficient implementation, since we here will calculate `f x` multiple times per item. I leave it as an exercise to optimize this further.

Note that in Haskell there is a [**`maximum :: (Foldable f, Ord a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) function that works on `Foldable`s. This thus will work with a list, a `Tree`, etc. One can define a `maximumBy` or something similar that operates on a `Foldable` as well, by slightly altering the "fold function".

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I can add another typeclass into my typeclass. Thanks again!